# MongoDB Mapping Referenced Relationships In Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

If I have two collections: Users and Events. A user can have many events...

```
Users
{

   Username: "Mark",
   Password: "1234567"
}

Events
{
   EventTitle: "Skiing",
   EventDate: "20/2/2015"
}
```

I need to associate an event with a user based on his username in java. So what I did was searching for the user....

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Username", "Mark");
DBCursor cursor = table.find(query);
```

and I searched for the event based on its title...

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("EventTitle", "Skiing");
DBCursor cursor = table.find(query);
```

I just need to know how to associate that event with the user, assuming that only one event and one user would result from the search queries. There is a lack of examples on the internet.

Comment: check out the quick-tour for examples, http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/.  Since the user has many events then you should update the user record and append all of the events to this record, this way you can just search for the user to add and remove events from his list of events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with NoSQL databases, stop thinking in SQL. Stop normalizing the data. Do not try to make the data relational. Duplicating data is perfectly fine. Sometimes desired.

You can for example put `Username`, or `User ObjectId`, or both in `Event` document either in an array, or create one `Event` document per `User`/`Event` combination.

All in all it really depends on what other queries you will be running.

Comment: this answer it's not useful. You may need to store a graph in a nosql database and the last thing you want is to create multiple nodes for a node that is referenced by more than one node. You want the node to be a reference in memory, not its serialized value for each node referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create another collection which is going to store such relation, first add a field "id" to both collections (this is always a good practice) and then you can relate one collection with each other through these IDs.

```
Users
{
   id: "001",
   Username: "Mark",
   Password: "1234567"
}

Events
{
   id: "001",
   EventTitle: "Skiing",
   EventDate: "20/2/2015"
}

Users_Events
{
   user_id: "001",
   event_id: "001"
}
```